# How do I properly add new plugins with LazyVim?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

[My config structure for neovim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOsPa.png) As you can see my folders structure. The nvimtree and undotree are installed with lazyvim easily with given guide from github. I don't really know How it works, I am good at existing config. But I want to add new plugins like NvimDap and many more. I don't really know what is the exact way of doing. First of all I added kickstart code for init.lua.
I want to know, how to properly add installation code for new lazyvim plugins in plugins folder and what to add in init.lua and how to make it work. I get too many errors of file not found while installing plugins. I have mason, lazyvim, treesitter etc. You can see my entire config at github.com/NewsonUpreti/My-neovim-config , According to that, How can I add nvim dap for now and any other plugins properly with lazyvim.

Thanks in Advance.

I did add new lua file with code to install plugin in my plugins folder using lazyvim. And I call the functions from init.lua saying require("pluginname") It worked for nvimtree and undotree with the same way, But doesn't work with most plugins like nvim-dap. What am I missing?